How to hit a SOAP API via WSDL using .NET?
My current project entails consuming SOAP APIs to upload Case data to a vendor's DB.  The vendor supplied WSDL files—one of which is supplied at the end of this body.
I referenced this service via WFC using Visual Studio's Reference Service... feature in a .NET 4.8 console application.  Doing so created the necessary ProgramService file and partially updated my App.Config.  I received the following comment in the App.config file:
<!-- WsdlImporter encountered unrecognized policy assertions in ServiceDescription 'http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/5.30/core/program': -->
<!-- <wsdl:binding name='ProgramPortBinding'> -->
<!--     <ns0:SupportingTokens xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">..</ns0:SupportingTokens> -->

It seems like part of the WSDL (specifically, the authentication part) wasn't properly translated to App.config.  I tried providing the credentials manually in Program.cs by instantiating ProgramPortTypeClient() and updating its ClientCredentials field, but I received the following error: Error on verifying message against security policy code:1000
I've spent the last few hours researching this issue and trying different solutions; however, nothing quite worked.  Do you know what's wrong?  If so, can you please explain what happened and how I may fix it?
Thank you.

Update: I updated the App.config file, and am now I'm getting a FaultException: Failed to assert identify with UsernameToken response.  I suspect this is because my App.config file doesn't properly account for the security type associated with the WSDL.  I still can't quite crack it.  App.config is as follows:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <startup>
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.8" />
    </startup>
    <runtime>
        <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-6.0.0.0" newVersion="6.0.0.0" />
            </dependentAssembly>
        </assemblyBinding>
    </runtime>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <behaviors>
            <endpointBehaviors>
                <behavior name="UsernameTokenBehavior">
                    <clientCredentials>

                    </clientCredentials>
                </behavior>
            </endpointBehaviors>
        </behaviors>
        <bindings>
            <customBinding>
                <binding name="ProgramPortBinding">
                    <textMessageEncoding messageVersion="Soap12" />
                    <security authenticationMode="UserNameOverTransport">
                        <secureConversationBootstrap />
                    </security>
                    <httpsTransport />
                </binding>
            </customBinding>
        </bindings>
        <client>
            <endpoint address="https://bottomline.legal-x.com:443/ws/5.30/core/ProgramService"
                binding="customBinding" bindingConfiguration="ProgramPortBinding"
                contract="ProgramService.ProgramPortType" name="ProgramPort"
                behaviorConfiguration="UsernameTokenBehavior" />
        </client>
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>


WSDL URL: https://bottomline.legal-x.com/ws/5.30/core/ProgramService?wsdl
WSDL Content:
<definitions xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:tns="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/5.30/core/program" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsp="http://www.w3.org/ns/ws-policy" xmlns:wsp1_2="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:wssutil="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" name="ProgramService530" targetNamespace="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/5.30/core/program">
<wsp:UsingPolicy wssutil:Required="true"/>
<wsp1_2:Policy wssutil:Id="Wssp1.2-2007-UsernameToken-Plain">
<ns0:SupportingTokens xmlns:ns0="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702">
<wsp1_2:Policy>
<ns0:UsernameToken ns0:IncludeToken="http://docs.oasis-open.org/ws-sx/ws-securitypolicy/200702/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
<wsp1_2:Policy>
<ns0:WssUsernameToken10/>
</wsp1_2:Policy>
</ns0:UsernameToken>
</wsp1_2:Policy>
</ns0:SupportingTokens>
</wsp1_2:Policy>
<types>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/5.30/core/program" schemaLocation="https://bottomline.legal-x.com:443/ws/5.30/core/ProgramService?xsd=1"/>
</xsd:schema>
<xsd:schema>
<xsd:import namespace="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/faults" schemaLocation="https://bottomline.legal-x.com:443/ws/5.30/core/ProgramService?xsd=2"/>
</xsd:schema>
</types>
<message name="ping">
<part element="tns:ping" name="parameters"/>
</message>
<message name="pingResponse">
<part element="tns:pingResponse" name="parameters"/>
</message>
<message name="getPrograms">
<part element="tns:getProgramsRequest" name="parameters"/>
</message>
<message name="getProgramsResponse">
<part element="tns:getProgramsResponse" name="parameters"/>
</message>
<message name="ValidationFaultException">
<part xmlns:ns1="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/faults" element="ns1:ValidationFault" name="fault"/>
</message>
<portType name="ProgramPortType">
<operation name="ping">
<input message="tns:ping" wsam:Action="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/5.30/core/program/ProgramPortType/pingRequest"/>
<output message="tns:pingResponse" wsam:Action="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/5.30/core/program/ProgramPortType/pingResponse"/>
</operation>
<operation name="getPrograms">
<input message="tns:getPrograms" wsam:Action="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/5.30/core/program/ProgramPortType/getProgramsRequest"/>
<output message="tns:getProgramsResponse" wsam:Action="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/5.30/core/program/ProgramPortType/getProgramsResponse"/>
<fault message="tns:ValidationFaultException" name="ValidationFaultException" wsam:Action="http://portal.allegientsystems.com/ws/5.30/core/program/ProgramPortType/getPrograms/Fault/ValidationFaultException"/>
</operation>
</portType>
<binding name="ProgramPortBinding" type="tns:ProgramPortType">
<wsp:PolicyReference URI="#Wssp1.2-2007-UsernameToken-Plain"/>
<soap12:binding style="document" transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http"/>
<operation name="ping">
<soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</output>
</operation>
<operation name="getPrograms">
<soap12:operation soapAction=""/>
<input>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</input>
<output>
<soap12:body use="literal"/>
</output>
<fault name="ValidationFaultException">
<soap12:fault name="ValidationFaultException" use="literal"/>
</fault>
</operation>
</binding>
<service name="ProgramService530">
<port binding="tns:ProgramPortBinding" name="ProgramPort">
<soap12:address location="https://bottomline.legal-x.com:443/ws/5.30/core/ProgramService"/>
</port>
</service>
</definitions>

